# How to push data from nodejs to browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

I am trying to understand how to push data from my nodejs server.js to my browser. Based on my web search I have found this [script](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-simplenode2-app/index.html):

**Server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var userCount = 0;
var userbytwo = 0; /* added var definition for userbytwo here */

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  userCount = userCount + 1;
  /* add statement to increment userbytwo by two here */
  userbytwo = userbytwo + 2;
  console.log('userCount: '+userCount+' userbytwo: '+userbytwo);
  res.render('index', {userCount: userCount, userbytwo: userbytwo});
 /* updated this line */
});
```

**index.html**

```
The user count in my nodejs application is: <%= userCount %>

The user by two count in my nodejs application is: <%= userbytwo %>
```

I expect that `<%= userCount %>` and `<%= userbytwo %>` will be filled, if I have started the **server.js**. But it doesn't.

1) What is wrong with my script?

2) How can I push data into the browser (index.html)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks Peteris, with your hint I got the last mile by myself. The index.ejs file has to be in the directory ".../views". Now does it work.

Comment: BTW, why I'm punished for my attempt to learn?

Answer (score 1):

`app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('POST request to the homepage');
});`

See more information in this tutorial:

http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: Thanks, ayoub. I don't like to overwrite my site. I just like to change parts of it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first set the view engine to `ejs` as the article suggests:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Then, rename your view file `index.ejs` instead of `index.html` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Just to check: 1) is `index.ejs` in the `/views` directory? 2) have you started the server using `app.listen`? For example, with the following line: `app.listen(3000);`. Let me know if not and I can update the answer. Thanks